# Filter Query returns only one result, but there are over 70K results

Tags: solr

I am running solr 7.7.1 and there is a strange behaviour with my field "price".If I issue a filter query on it, there is only one result I am getting back, while there are over 70.000 documents with a value for this field. E.g.: `"price":638,`

I believe that I have the same configuration on a local machine, where the filter query does work. After comparing the two shemas the only difference I found is, that on the non working version the shema points to 70.750 docs, while the non working does not have this value.

My fq: `price:[1 TO 200000]`

Full query:

```
fq=price%3A%5B*%20TO%20*%5D&q=*%3A*
```

Field type:

```
<fieldType name="price" class="solr.IntPointField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" docValues="true"/>
```

field:

```
<field name="price" type="price" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"  />
```

shema:

```
Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.IntPointField  
Docs:70,750
```

On the same non working machine, I do have another core running with an older config, where the fq returns good results.

The query `price:[* TO *]` returns only 1 result as well.

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you show the whole query you're executing?

Comment: Added to question. I am using now the admin interface where I just added the fq as indicated.

Comment: Filters on other values do work. It might be related to the "docValues" I added recently. Could this be a missing configuration option?

Comment: Did you reindex after adding docValues?

Comment: Yes I did, twice and I restarted solr.

Comment: OK, stupid me. Just did a second restart and reindex,, just to make sure. It works now. Must be me, or the machines ;-) Thank you for the hint!